# can't access static method of a simple cs file in xaml.cs file

Tags: class, windows-phone-8, methods, static

I'm creating an app for my semester project. In this project I have a simple class file and a few xaml pages. In one xaml page the code checks the value of a string and depending on that value runs a countdown timer. If the value of string is equal to a certain string then it should call a method from simple class where the value of string is changed and then it should navigate to the next xaml page.

When I call the function the application breaks. No error or anything, it just breaks. I don't know why. I have called other functions of same class file in other xaml files and they work perfect but here I'm having trouble. I guess it has something to do with timer.

xaml.cs:

```
namespace TrafficGuru
{
    public partial class Page2 : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        DispatcherTimer countDownTimer;
        int check;

        public Page2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            tbl.Text = global.str;
            if (global.str == "YOUR LIGHT IS ON FOR : ")
            {
                check = 0;
            }
            if (global.str == "YOUR LIGHT WILL BE ON IN:")
            {
                check = 1;
            }
            if (global.str == "YOUR LIGHT WILL NOT BE ON FOR UNTIL ATLEAST " + global.x * 15 + " MORE SECS.YOU WILL GET AN UPDATE IN:")
            {
                check = 2;
            }
            countDownTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            countDownTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
            countDownTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(countDownTimerEvent);
            countDownTimer.Start();




            test.Content = "" + "seconds remaining";
        }
        int count = global.cdt;

        void test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
        void countDownTimerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            test.Content = count + " Seconds";


            if (count > 0)
            {
                count--;
            }
            else if (count == 0)
            {
              if (check == 0)
                {
                    test.Content = "STOP!!";


                }
                else if (check == 1)
                {
                    test.Content = "GO!!!";


                }

                if(check==2)
                {
                  string x= global.rego();//the method i m trying to call its public and static





                    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page3.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));*/


                }
               }
            }



    }

}
```

globalx class code::

```
if (x == 1)
                    {
                        str = "YOUR LIGHT WILL BE ON IN:";
                    }

                    cdt = x*15;

                    l[m].resetcount();
                    a[m] = 0;
                    l[m].setlight("RED");
                    c = 9;

                }

            if (l[0].getcount() == 0 || s > 0)
            {
                l[0].Createcar();
            }
            a[0] += l[0].getcount();
            t[0] = l[0].gettime();
            if (l[1].getcount() == 0 || s > 0)
            {
                l[1].Createcar();
            }
            a[1] += l[1].getcount();
            t[1] = l[1].gettime();
            if (l[2].getcount() == 0 || s > 0)
            {
                l[2].Createcar();
            }
            a[2] = l[2].getcount();
            t[2] = l[2].gettime();

            if (l[3].getcount() == 0 || s > 0)
            {
                l[3].Createcar();
            }
            a[3] += l[3].getcount();
            t[3] = l[3].gettime();
            s++;
            if (s % 2 != 0)
            {
                var now1 = DateTime.Now;
                tv = (now1 - begin).TotalMilliseconds;
                tym = Convert.ToInt32(tv);
                int[] pkl = { 0, 0 };
                maxi(a, t, s, tym, ref pkl);
                m = pkl[0];
            }
            else
            {
                var now1 = DateTime.Now;
                tv = (now1 - begin).TotalMilliseconds;
                tym = Convert.ToInt32(tv);
                int[] pkj = { 0, 0 };
                maxi(a, t, s, tym, ref pkj);
                q = pkj[0];
            }
            return str;
        }
```

COMPLETE GLOBAL CLASS WITH GO AND REGO

public static class globalx
    {
        public static int n;
        public static int s;
        public static int m;
        public static int q;
        public static int c;
        public static int f;
        public static lane[] l = new lane[4];
        public static double tv;
        public static int tym;
        public static int[] a = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        public static int[] t = new int[4];
        public static string str="asdf";
        public static int cdt; //countdowntime
        public static int x;
        public static DateTime begin;

```
    public static void start()
    {

        begin = DateTime.Now;

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        { l[i] = new lane(); }



        var now = DateTime.Now;
        tv = (now - begin).TotalMilliseconds;
        tym = Convert.ToInt32(tv);
        l[0].Createcar();
        a[0] += l[0].getcount();
        t[0] = l[0].gettime();

        l[1].Createcar();
        a[1] += l[1].getcount();
        t[1] = l[1].gettime();

        l[2].Createcar();
        a[2] += l[2].getcount();
        t[2] = l[2].gettime();

        l[3].Createcar();
        a[3] += l[3].getcount();
        t[3] = l[3].gettime();
        now = DateTime.Now;
        tv = (now - begin).TotalMilliseconds;
        tym = Convert.ToInt32(tv);
        int[] r = { 88, 99 };
        maxi(a, t, s, tym, ref r);
        m = r[0];
        q = r[1];
        c = 0;
        f = 9;
    }
    public static string go()
   {

            l[m].setlight("GREEN");
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            tv = (now - begin).TotalMilliseconds;
            tym = Convert.ToInt32(tv);
            l[m].settime(tym);
            if (n == m + 1)
            {
                c = 0;
                str = "YOUR LIGHT IS ON FOR : ";
                cdt = 15;

                l[m].resetcount();
                a[m] = 0;
                l[m].setlight("RED");

            }
            if (n == q + 1)
            {
                c = 9;
                str = "YOUR LIGHT WILL BE ON IN:";
                cdt = 15;
                                    l[m].resetcount();
                a[m] = 0;
                l[m].setlight("RED");
            }
            if (n != m + 1 && n != q + 1)
            {
                x = m + 1 - n;
                if (x < 0)
                {
                    x = 0 - x;
                }

                str = "YOUR LIGHT WILL NOT BE ON FOR UNTIL ATLEAST " + x * 15 + " MORE SECS.YOU WILL GET AN UPDATE IN:";
                if (x == 1)
                {
                    str = "YOUR LIGHT WILL BE ON IN:";
                }

                cdt = x*15;
                a[m] = 0;
                l[m].setlight("RED");
                c = 9;

            }

        if (l[0].getcount() == 0 || s > 0)
        {
            l[0].Createcar();
        }
        a[0] += l[0].getcount();
        t[0] = l[0].gettime();
        if (l[1].getcount() == 0 || s > 0)
        {
            l[1].Createcar();
        }
        a[1] += l[1].getcount();
        t[1] = l[1].gettime();
        if (l[2].getcount() == 0 || s > 0)
        {
            l[2].Createcar();
        }
        a[2] = l[2].getcount();
        t[2] = l[2].gettime();

        if (l[3].getcount() == 0 || s > 0)
        {
            l[3].Createcar();
        }
        a[3] += l[3].getcount();
        t[3] = l[3].gettime();
        s++;
        if (s % 2 != 0)
        {
            var now1 = DateTime.Now;
            tv = (now1 - begin).TotalMilliseconds;
            tym = Convert.ToInt32(tv);
            int[] pkl = { 0, 0 };
            maxi(a, t, s, tym, ref pkl);
            m = pkl[0];
        }
        else
        {
            var now1 = DateTime.Now;
            tv = (now1 - begin).TotalMilliseconds;
            tym = Convert.ToInt32(tv);
            int[] pkj = { 0, 0 };
            maxi(a, t, s, tym, ref pkj);
            q = pkj[0];
        }
        return str;
    }
    public static string rego()

    {

        {

            l[q].setlight("GREEN");
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            tv = (now - begin).TotalMilliseconds;
            tym = Convert.ToInt32(tv);
            l[q].settime(tym);

            if (n == q + 1)
            {
                f = 0;
                str = "YOUR LIGHT IS ON FOR : ";
                cdt=15;
            }
            if (n == m + 1)
            {

                str = "YOUR LIGHT WILL BE ON IN:";
                cdt=15;
                l[q].resetcount();
                a[q] = 0;
                l[q].setlight("RED");
                f = 9;
            }
            if (n != m + 1 && n != q + 1)
            {
                x = m + 1 - n;
                if (x < 0)
                {
                    x = 0 - x;
                }

                str = "YOUR LIGHT WILL NOT BE ON FOR UNTIL ATLEAST " + x * 15 + " MORE SECS.YOU WILL GET AN UPDATE IN:";
                if (x == 1)
                {
                    str = "YOUR LIGHT WILL BE ON IN:";
                }
                cdt = x * 15;

                a[q] = 0;
                l[q].setlight("RED");
                f = 9;
            }
        }

        if (l[0].getcount() == 0 || s > 0)
        {
            l[0].Createcar();
        }
        a[0] += l[0].getcount();
        t[0] = l[0].gettime();
        if (l[1].getcount() == 0 || s > 0)
        {
            l[1].Createcar();
        }
        a[1] += l[1].getcount();
        t[1] = l[1].gettime();
        if (l[2].getcount() == 0 || s > 0)
        {
            l[2].Createcar();
        }
        a[2] = l[2].getcount();
        t[2] = l[2].gettime();

        if (l[3].getcount() == 0 || s > 0)
        {
            l[3].Createcar();
        }
        a[3] += l[3].getcount();
        t[3] = l[3].gettime();
        s++;
        if (s % 2 != 0)
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            tv = (now - begin).TotalMilliseconds;
            tym = Convert.ToInt32(tv);
            int[] pkl = { 0, 0 };
            maxi(a, t, s, tym, ref pkl);
            m = pkl[0];
        }
        else
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            tv = (now - begin).TotalMilliseconds;
            tym = Convert.ToInt32(tv);
            int[] pkj = { 0, 0 };
            maxi(a, t, s, tym, ref pkj);
            q = pkj[0];
        }
        return str;

    }
```

Comment: Do you really have a type called `global`? I'd change that to start with, so that it follows .NET naming conventions and doesn't conflict with a contextual keyword. (I'd also fix all your method and property names to conform with .NET naming conventions.) This won't fix your error, but it will at least make your code more pleasant for other people to read.

Comment: i m a beginner at this so i apologize for the sloppiness. global is also a public static class and go() is a public static method.i dont get an error at all. its just that the app breaks.plz help me fix it

Comment: Can you please add the code for global, se we can see what it does, how it is defined and even to test it.

Comment: is it rego() or go()?? in the code you provide it is rego() and in your comment it is go().

Comment: rego and go both do samething.i cant call either one of them. i have changed the class name to globalx on your suggestion.here is the code.dont mind objects of other classes in it.they work fine. just tell me how to make this func work::

Comment: i have added the code for globalx in question.plz take a look at it and help

Comment: DreamNet??any suggestions??

Comment: Dude where is the code for go() and rego()? plz provide it with it signiture

Comment: I have posted it.plz do check it

Comment: are you there man?? i really need some help

Comment: Reduce the scope of this. Clearly name all your variables. m, l, a, t are terrible names and don't help us to know what's going on. Also, how does it "just break"? .Net is very good about giving errors, so I'd be surprised if it just stopped.

Comment: Can you check if the problem is not connected with `Navigate()` in timer Tick? - Navigation is done asynchronously and if you try to Navigate twice at the same time, your app will break. Is it possible that this part of code is fired twice in one second interval?

Comment: it breaks means that it just closes and emulator goes to homescreen or start screen.and navigate is not the isssue.if i comment out the call to to function above navigate command it does navigate to next page bt if i put the call to function above it ,app breaks

Answer (score 0):

Sourround your code with try catch and see what's the message.

```
  try

    {
       // Your Code
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    Debug.writeline(ex.Message);

    }
```

Comment: thanx.i tried it.it says index was outside the bounds of array. i dont get it.do you? if yes then plz tellme how to fix it

Comment: thanx alot:-) i finally figured it out.there was a problem in an array in function go().fixed it and now it works. Thanx alot to u and every one else

Comment: If this helped you please accept the answer (click the tick icon)